# My jwt bearer token returns error="invalid_token", error_description="The token expired" with postman

Tags: .net-core, jwt, postman

I´m following a tutorial about microservices. I got to the point of using bearer tokens for a basic authorization model. I create the token and set all the properties but when I try to use the token it gives me the error: `Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token expired at '04/03/2020 21:47:31'"` even tho its currently 21:42 so its not actually expired.

Im just checking to this url: https://localhost:5001/api/Activities/GetActivity

Could it be a problem with postman, I already trying changing the issuer, adding more than 5 minutes, adding more headers to postman and no luck.

This is my function to create the token:

```
 public CustomJsonWebToken Create(Guid userId)
        {
            var nowUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var expiration = nowUtc.AddMinutes(jwtOptions.ExpiryMinutes);
            var centuryBegin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToUniversalTime();
            var exp = (long)(new TimeSpan(expiration.Ticks - centuryBegin.Ticks).TotalSeconds);
            var now = (long)(new TimeSpan(nowUtc.Ticks - centuryBegin.Ticks).TotalSeconds);
            var payload = new JwtPayload
            {
                {"sub", userId},
                {"iss", jwtOptions.Issuer},
                {"iat", now},
                {"exp", exp},
                {"unique_name", userId}
            };
            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(jwtHeader, payload);
            var token = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(jwt);

            return new CustomJsonWebToken
            {
                Token = token,
                Expire = exp
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely problem is that the `centuryBegin` you used is not the UTC Epoch - the `DateTime` constructor by default assumes its `Kind` to be `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, and calling `ToUniversalTime()` won't change that fact that .NET assumes it to represent the instance of time at 1 Jan 1970 *in your local timezone*.

So for it to represent the Epoch correctly you should probably use:

```
var centuryBegin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `DateTimeOffset` class instead because it is more suited for representation of an absolute time, and it also has the convenient method `DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds()`:

```
var nowUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
var expiration = nowUtc.AddMinutes(jwtOptions.ExpiryMinutes);
var exp = expiration.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
var now = nowUtc.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it worked perfectly, I didnt know about that class, I have a lot to learn! Thanks a ton. Just a question, would you mind telling me whats the benefits of using ToUnixSeconds instead of just using only the nowUtc.AddMinutes(jwtOptions.ExpiryMinutes); as the expiration time?

Comment: @Teler `ToUnixTimeSeconds` just saves you the effort from subtracting the two times to get the Unix timestamp. You'll still need `nowUtc.AddMinutes(jwtOptions.ExpiryMinutes)` to create the expiration time first.

Comment: For more detailed discussions of `DateTime` vs `DateTimeOffset`, you can see [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime) on Microsoft Docs